# How to observe object's property in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have the following `Forecast` class:

```
class Forecast {

    let city: City

     var currentTemperature: String {
        didSet {
            print("cur tepm was set to \(currentTemperature)")
        }
    }

    init(city: City) {
        self.city = city
        self.currentTemperature = "0"
    }

    func loadForecast() {
        self.currentTemperature = "+10"
    }

}
```

I am trying to observe `currentTemperature` property of `forecast` object in `ForecastViewModel`

```
class ForecastViewModel {

    fileprivate let variableForecast: Variable<Forecast>

    var navigationTitle: Observable<String> {
        return Observable.just("No name")
    }

    init(forecast aForecast: Forecast) {
        self.variableForecast = Variable(aForecast)

        self.variableForecast.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (s) in
            print(s.currentTemperature)
        })

        variableForecast.value.currentTemperature  = "-15"
        variableForecast.value.loadForecast()
    }

}
```

However, code in subscribe on next is executed only once and prints 0. `didSet` block is called every time.

How should I observe a property of this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should declare `currentTemperature` as `Variable` to observe the value changes. Your `Forecast` will become as this

```
class Forecast {

    let city: City

     var currentTemperature: Variable<String> = Variable("0")

    init(city: City) {
        self.city = city
    }

    func loadForecast() {
        self.currentTemperature.value = "+10"
    }

}
```

So now you can subscribe to listen the changes in `currentTemperature` as below,

```
class ForecastViewModel {

    fileprivate let variableForecast: Variable<Forecast>

    var navigationTitle: Observable<String> {
        return Observable.just("No name")
    }

    init(forecast aForecast: Forecast) {
        self.variableForecast = Variable(aForecast)


self.variableForecast.value.currentTemperature.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            print(value)
        })

        variableForecast.value.currentTemperature.value  = "-15"
        variableForecast.value.loadForecast()
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without declaring it as variable? I wanted to have a model class independent from rx code

Comment: I don't think so. One way is to create this inside `ForecastViewModel` and initialize its value from the `forecast` model in `init` of `ForecastViewModel`. Then in its `.subscribe` callback. update value in forecast model.